# Nested partials and templates; How to implement a conditional view or editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I've been using C# for a while, and have done my share of web-forms, but I'm very new to MVC and I don't really know how to phrase this question to get help from the googles.

I'm developing an MVC site backed by EF and just trying to get the hang of things. So I have a view which allows the User to Create an entity "A". Entity A has a reference to entity B, it's address, which in turn has a reference to entity C, the address' region.

So I've figured out that I can create an Editor Template which can be injected into the Create view for entity A, and returns the A model with it's entity B reference populated. I can do the same thing on the entity B template, injecting an editor template for entity C and getting back the correct entity in B's reference property.

My problem is that entity C is a rarely created entity. The User needs the ability to create one, and it's a very trivial entity (has name and country_enum), so I don't want the user to have to visit a special page just to create this entity after they've figured out that the correct C entity isn't yet in the list, then come back to the page and reenter all the other fields they might have already filled.

How can I create a "conditional" view or set of views, which will allow the user to either select an existing entity C, or create a new entity C if they need to, without leaving the Create - Entity A page?

For clarity this is my current setup:

EntityA-Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.HiddenFor(A => A.ParentID)
  <fieldset>
    //Entity A editors etc...
    @Html.EditorFor(A => A.Address, "Address.cshtml", null)
  </fieldset>      
}
```

EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml

```
@model Models.Address
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(B => B.Property1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  //Entity B Property editors etc...
</div>
@Html.EditorFor(B=> B.Region, "Region.cshtml", null)
```

In the second view/template, I need a way to render either a full "Create new region" editor template (which it does now), OR a "select existing region from dropdown" view/template/etc, which will still return the Region model the same way it currently does (or close to). My preference would be to avoid JS as much as possible with this solution, but you're the experts!

Comment: If you don't want your 'Add new region' button to redirect to a new page, then you will need javascript/jquery to display a popup form to enter the new region details, then post it using ajax and if successful, add the new region to the dropdownlist (and select it)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Select List with your domain Regions. I personaly use my View Model for such methods.

```
        public class Address
        {
            public Address()
            {
                Regions  = new List<SelectListItem>();
            }
            //Your Address Properties
            public int SelectedRegionId {get; set;}
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Regions {get; set;}
            //You can fill the Regions list in the controller, or in the contructor
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateRegionsSelectList()
            {
                var regions = new List<SelectListItem>();
                var domainRegions = // Get your regions from Repository;

                foreach (var region in domainRegions)
                    regions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = region.Name, Value = region.Id};
            }
        }
```

Then you can create drop down for your domain Regions in the Address Editor:

```
@model Models.Address
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(B => B.Property1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  //Entity B Property editors etc...
</div>
Select Existing Region: @Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedRegionId, Model.Regions, new {Name = "Address.SelectedRegionId"})
Or Create New Region: <input id="createRegion" type="button" value="Create Region" />
<div id="regionsEditorWrapper" display:"style:none">
@Html.EditorFor(B=> B.Region, "Region.cshtml", null)
</div>
```

And show the hidden editor with simple jQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#createRegion").click(function(){
        $("#regionsEditorWrapper").show();
    });
});
```

If you select from the drop-down and post, you should get the region id in your Post Action Method. I haven't tested this, but it should give you direction. Try it. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to quite work as-is, granted there's a good chance I'm doing it wrong. I was playing with composite models on this view, and as such I've added the SelectedID property to that model. The first time, the form rendered, but I didn't get either property back (both null). I changed... something? And now the entire region editor refuses to render. Still, I think you're on the right track with this, and I will continue fiddling as I do with MVC and report back when I get it right.

Comment: The name of the drop-down should be `Address.SelectedRegionId`, asuming you use composite view model. I had name it wrong. Also, you need to pass HtmlFiledPrefix to your Editors to name the properties right.